# Its not coming out of the loop

Tags: java, android

Hi in the below code **mandatoryCount = 0** and it should be increased when an image is selected but its found to be always 1 and i cant exit the loop can any one help me. Here if **mandatoryCount = 0 or mandatoryCount>=imageTypeMandatory.length**. It must come out of loop. But this code is working if i comment the mandatory count ==0. I cannot find the exact error.

```
if (dataOne.getCount() >= 1) {
mandatoryCount=0;                                   
dataOne.moveToFirst();             
while(!dataOne.isAfterLast()){                                  
for(int iCopy=0;iCopy<imageTypeMandatory.length;iCopy++){                               if(imageTypeMandatory[iCopy].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dataOne.getString(0).trim())){
mandatoryCount++;                               imageTypeMandatoryCopy[iCopy]="";
}}          
dataOne.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: Which loop are you referring to? What is your question?

Comment: @JasonC   for(int iCopy=0;iCopy<imageTypeMandatory.length;iCopy++){

                                if(imageTypeMandatory[iCopy].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dataOne.getString(0).trim())){
                                    mandatoryCount++;
                                    imageTypeMandatoryCopy[iCopy]="";
                                }

Comment: Must not `getString(0)` be `getString(1)` (one-based)?

Comment: @JoopEggen I tried changing to 1 but its not working

Comment: I solved the problem as i was trying to do `imageTypeMandatory = imageTypeMandatoryCopy;` but it was not working instead i added the values of the arrays like `imageTypeMandatory = new String[]{"x","y","z"}; imageTypeMandatoryCopy =new String[]{"x","y","z"};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is testing the moveFirst/moveNext.

```
if (dataOne.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        for(int iCopy=0;iCopy<imageTypeMandatory.length;iCopy++){
            if(imageTypeMandatory[iCopy].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dataOne.getString(0).trim())){
                mandatoryCount++;
                imageTypeMandatoryCopy[iCopy]="";
            }   
        }
    } while(dataOne.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem as i was trying to do `imageTypeMandatory = imageTypeMandatoryCopy;` but it was not working instead i added the values of the arrays like `imageTypeMandatory = new String[]{"x","y","z"};  imageTypeMandatoryCopy =new String[]{"x","y","z"};`